# undefined method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm new to ruby and started to create my *nd toy app.
I:

1. Created controller 'questions'
2. Created model 'question'
3. Created controller action 'new'
4. Added 'New.html.erb' file

in erb file I use `form_for` helper and and `new` controller action where I instantiate 
`@question` instance variable.
When I try to run this I get `'undefined method: questions_path for #<ActionView::Base:0x5be5e24>'` error.
Below is my new.html.erb:

```
<%form_for @question do |f| %>
   <%=f.text_field :title %>
<%end%>
```

Please advise how to fix this and also help me with aliasing this controller action.
What I mean is I would like to type http://mysite/questions/ask, instead of /questions/create

Comment: Did you add anything to your routes.rb file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `config/routes.rb` you will need to add:

```
map.resources :questions
```

to fix the undefined method questions_path problem.

One way to get `/questions/ask` is to modify `routes.rb` like so:

```
map.ask_question '/questions/ask', :controller => 'questions', :action => 'create'
```

which will give you `ask_question_path` which you can reference in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did all of these steps individually.  You should try out the scaffold generator, which will build all of this for you.

Example:

```
>ruby script/generate scaffold question question:string answer:string votes:integer
  exists  app/models/
  exists  app/controllers/
  exists  app/helpers/
  create  app/views/questions
  exists  app/views/layouts/
  exists  test/functional/
  exists  test/unit/
  exists  public/stylesheets/
  create  app/views/questions/index.html.erb
  create  app/views/questions/show.html.erb
  create  app/views/questions/new.html.erb
  create  app/views/questions/edit.html.erb
  create  app/views/layouts/questions.html.erb
  create  public/stylesheets/scaffold.css
  create  app/controllers/questions_controller.rb
  create  test/functional/questions_controller_test.rb
  create  app/helpers/questions_helper.rb
  route  map.resources :questions
  dependency  model
  exists    app/models/
  exists    test/unit/
  exists    test/fixtures/
  create    app/models/question.rb
  create    test/unit/question_test.rb
  create    test/fixtures/questions.yml
  create    db/migrate
  create    db/migrate/20081201150131_create_questions.rb
```

So as you can see, with a scaffold we get our model, our controller, our views, our route, a database migration that will build a Questions table with two fields, and RESTful controller actions to immediately add/update/view/delete any question data.  Oh, and most importantly, an empty set of test files ready for your tests to be written :).

Comment: hi, thanks for quick response. I opted for manual way because I wanted to 'grok' the inner steps the scaffolding performs, and of course, stuck :-)